# SimpleJwtAuthentication problem ...Even after presence of user ,url not giving token

Tags: python, django, authentication

i am using this model extending from *abstractuser* but even after successfully creating user i am not able to get the tokens....
Tokens are genrerated only for those which i created through python manage.py createsuperuser ..others not working.
why????
i am using simplejwt authentication.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.
class user_model(AbstractUser):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    age=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    dob=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
        path('signup/',include('userdata.urls')),
        path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
        path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
        path('loggedIn/',include("notes.urls")),
        
    ]
```